# Finding permutations $\sigma\in S_4$ satisfying $\sigma^2=(1\;2)(3\;4)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I am struggling to find the answer to the following question:
Find all $\sigma\in S_4$ satisfying
$σ^2 = (1\;2)(3\;4)$

Can somebody please explain the way to find these?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, since there are only 24 elements in $S_4$, you could simply list them all and square them... (But once you start doing that, you will probably figure out a smarter way after a while.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** To be consistent, we always write the smallest number in the cycle first, in this case $1$.

What type of shape could $\sigma$ take?  Could it be a 3cycle?  Could it be two 2cycles?  Must it be a 4cycle?

Supposing it were a 4cycle, we begin writing it like so: $(1~*~*~*)$.  Since $\sigma^2=(1~2)(3~4)$, what does that imply about where $2$ should be located in the above?

Comment: Is it correct that it can't be a 3-cycle or 2-cycle as no element is mapped to itself in $\sigma^{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, calculating the $k$-th power of a cycle consists in jumping from one element to the $k$-th next element (position calculated modulo the cycle length).

So for a cycle $\gamma$ such that $\gamma^2=(1\,2)(3\,4)$, we know that $\gamma$ must have length $4$, and further that $\gamma=(1\,x\,2\,y)$, $x,y\in\{3,4\}$. So there are two solutions:
$$\gamma=(1\,3\,2\,4)\quad\text{and}\quad \gamma^{-1}=(1\,4\,2\,3). $$